# How do I add files to my folder? java

Tags: java, file, mkdir

My program is creating files and I'm needing to put them in a specific folder. Not sure of the process. Thanks

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\Blah\\Desktop\\blahblah\\FOLDER";
File bfFolder = new File (path);
bfFolder.mkdir();

for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
    try (DataOutputStream dataO = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file" + " a"))) {
```

Comment: `FileOutputStream(new File(file, "a"))`...I'd also check the result of `bfFolder.mkdir` to see if the directory was made correctly and check to see if it exists as well...

Comment: so where you put file, I should type (new FileOUtputStream (FOLDER, "file" + "a")) ?

Comment: since the folder I created is named FOLDER (path)

Comment: Sorry, it should be `FileOutputStream(new File(bfFolder , "a"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `File` to `new FileOutputStream()`. To create a new `File` inside the directory you created, pass the parent directory and the filename to the constructor:

```
// This will refer to C:\Users\Blah\Desktop\blahblah\FOLDER\name.txt
File myFile = new File(bfFolder, "name.txt");
try(FileOutputStream fStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    DataOutputStream data0 = new DataOutputStream(fStream)) {
```

Comment: Can you think of a more generic path to put this into? I know if I make it to blah's Desktop is will not work on anyone else's pc...

Comment: `System.getProperty("USER.HOME")` will give you the user's home directory as a `String`

Comment: any idea off the top of your head where NetBeans saves a project by default? The problem is, I currently have this set up to go where I have my file saved. However, when someone else uses this it's going to give them a FNFExc because the dont own the same file location.

Comment: Never mind, I don't think this file would have to be in the project folder in order to run, just read from the files I'm putting in. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Files.copy(), it's a quick way to do what you want.